# Mysql update a datetime field from an existing varchar field

Tags: mysql, datetime

I had to rebuild a table from a text file, and the data import created my datetime field as a string YY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss .. I have tried str_to_date and date functions, but nothing..

```
Update mydb set new-date-field = str_to_date( old-str-field, format );
```

Where format was various yy/mm/dd etc formats..

Thanks

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE()` should work for your use case with the query you provide. What date format did you try with it? `%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s` would be appropriate. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Why you don't use the application that has built the table from the text file to perform this task?

Comment: Please be absolutely specific about the data and what you have tried. Lets cut the guess work out of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truely have a text field of the format `yy/mm/dd hh:ii:ss` then you can do this to convert that string to a DateTime

```
UPDATE mytable set new_date_field = TIMESTAMP(old_str_field);
```

To test it first do this

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(old-str-field) as new_date_field FROM mytable;
```

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp

Comment: This worked.. I guess I must have gotten the date formatting off in my haste to recover the lost table..  Thank-you!